# How do we reconcile Isaiah 65:23 with Matthew 22:30?

Tags: matthew, isaiah, resurrection

“They shall not labor in vain, ***Nor bring forth children for trouble***; For they shall be the descendants of the blessed of the Lord, And their offspring with them.”
‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭65:23‬ ‭

WITH:

“**For in the resurrection they neither marry nor are given in marriage**, but are like angels of God in heaven.”
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭22:30‬ ‭

I searched other questions, I don’t think I found a parallel or repeat question.

**Q: How do we reconcile the new creation “giving birth” from people, with what Jesus taught?**

Comment: It is not evident that Isaiah 65:23 is referring to post-resurrection people, and without that being demonstrated there is nothing to reconcile. Questions like this may be better suited for [christianity.se] where they can be directed towards denominations with specific eschatological interpretations of the prophets.

Comment: It was in the context of the new creation Isaiah 65:17, so I am not sure I agree with you on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Not so fast - the OP's question tacitly assumes (without proof) that these two verses apply to the same situation.  They clearly do not.  More specifically,

- Isa 65:17-25 is a prophecy about the ideal Israel that should have occurred after the return from Babylon.  This can be ascertained by the reference to people dying (V20, 21) which will not occur after the resurrection.  That such an "ideal" Jerusalem never eventuated is a simple matter of history.
- Matt 22:30 is a prophecy about the sort of people we will be after the resurrection of the dead as described in much greater detail (eg, concerning heavenly bodies quite different from our earthly bodies) in 1 Cor 15.

Thus, the two passages are not at odds but speak of different situations completely.  However, many of the promises (not all) in Isa 65:17-25 can be expected to be fulfilled in the new earth after the resurrection of the dead, but that is another question.

Comment: Good answer, just make sure you know that the jews returned from babylon were a minority of the Jewish nation. Many jews still remained in Babylon, many in Persia, etc.. and also the 10 tribes was still scattered around the globe.

Comment: @Kapandaria - that is true and part of the problem - very few of Jews returned and so the prophecy was never fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

These two verses speaks about two different periods.

The first period, when Messiach will come at the end of the days (what known as "second coming" in Christianity), people will still get married and eat and drink as normal.

But the ressurection will occur many many years later, like 40-200 years after Messiach comes. And when the deads will rise from their tombs, the world will look completley different.

Answer (score -1):

The new heaven and new earth described in Isaiah 65:17-25, was not the same as the new heaven and new earth on Jesus 2nd coming. Isaiah prophesized a blessing to the exile, that the Lord would forget the former things of them when they returned to Jerusalem. The Lord would once again give blessing to Jerusalem and the people who live there.

Note verse 20. It still had infant and old man who lived a long life, but still would die.

> 20 “Never again will there be in it
> an infant who lives but a few days,
> or an old man who does not live out his years;
> the one who dies at a hundred
> will be thought a mere child;
> the one who fails to reach[a] a hundred
> will be considered accursed. (NIV)

Note verse 21. The new Jerusalem in Revelation 21 had the city completed, didn't need to build houses. There is the river of the water of life, on each side of the river stood the tree of life, bearing 12 crops of fruit, yielding its fruit every month. People no longer need to plant vineyards.

> 21 They will build houses and dwell in them;
> they will plant vineyards and eat their fruit.

So the new heaven and new earth of Isaiah was still an earthly realm, the time of the return of the exile. But it is an allusion to the new heaven and new earth in the End Day, that was the time Jesus in Matthew 22:30 referred to.

Comment: You are mixing up two prophecies. Prophecy often is like looking through a window at a vista beyond. Two distinct times are seen, but (almost) merged. Isaiah 65 is thus, Therefore, one needs to discern which 'Jerusalem' is being observed : Jerusalem below, or New Jerusalem descending out of heaven ?